# Kinect SDK requires Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, kinect-sdk

The Kinect for Windows SDK lists Visual Studio 2010/12 as one of its [software requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855359.aspx#Software_Requirements).

Why is this so? Is it not possible to program with the SDK in another IDE, say Eclipse?

Comment: My guess is that this is their attempt to bundle you into their products.  You could try simply installing an express version and not using it.  Eclipse ought to work if you can get all the references correct.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't support .Net languages does it? (Note: eclipse gives me nightmares)

Comment: Jnect for Eclipse - The Java to Kinect for Windows SDK bridge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can code also in Eclipse, please see the information in the video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJHR45u0wmo

and

also there is Jnect for Eclipse - The Java to Kinect for Windows SDK bridge http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Jnect-for-Eclipse-The-Java-to-Kinect-for-Windows-SDK-bridge